# How do I access all objects with ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How do I access all `fluxo.etapas` objects in `ng-repeat`? Now, I can only access the [0] collection.

```html
<div class="form-group" ng-repeat="aguardando in fluxo.etapas[0].aguardandoAssinaturas">
            <label>Details <strong>{{aguardando.nome}}</strong></label>
            <div class="input-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" value="{{aguardando.link}}" onclick="this.select();" />
            </div>
```

I need to access all items in this collection.

Comment: use nested `ng-repeat`

Comment: Please include enough code for a complete example. In this case, add some JavaScript.

Comment: looks like you are mixing Razor code with angular code. Won't work as they run in different environments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

**From**

```
<div class="form-group" ng-repeat="aguardando in fluxo.etapas[0].aguardandoAssinaturas">
```

**To**

```
<div class="form-group" ng-repeat="aguardando in fluxo.etapas">
```

Then you will be able to access the items inside using another ng-repeat

```
 <div class="form-group" ng-repeat="item in aguardando.aguardandoAssinaturas">
```

Answer (score 0):

is `fluxo-etapas` an array? if so you can ng-repeat over that, and then nest another ng-repeat inside for the `aguardandoAssinaturas`

so like

```
<div class="form-group" ng-repeat="item in fluxo.etapas">
   <div class="form-group" ng-repeat="aguardando in item.aguardandoAssinaturas">
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do an `ng-repeat` inside an `ng-repeat`, like this:

```
    <div class="form-group" ng-repeat="aguardando in fluxo.etapas">
<div ng-repeat="(key, value) in aguardando">
```